# Foreign key violation error on row insert

Tags: java, jdbc

While a am trying to insert values to following table via jdbc i am getting error

Database schema

```
CREATE TABLE student_contact_details_t(
    student_contact_details_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    student_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL ,
    contact_relation_type_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255),
    addresss varchar(255),
    phone_no varchar(255),
    created_by varchar(255),
    created_date DATE,
    modified_by varchar(255),
    modified_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY(student_contact_details_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES student_details_t(student_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(contact_relation_type_id) REFERENCES contact_relation_type_t(contact_relation_type_id)
);
```

Code

```
public void saveStudentContactDetails(
        StudentContactDetailsTO studentContactDetails)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {
    try {
        int autoId = 0;
        String Insertquery = "insert into student_contact_details_t(student_id,contact_relation_type_id,name,addresss,phone_no,created_by,created_date,modified_by,modified_date)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement prepareStatement = JDBCConnectionUtil
                .getConnection().prepareStatement(Insertquery,
                        Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ResultSet studentId = prepareStatement.getGeneratedKeys();

        prepareStatement.setInt(1, studentContactDetails.getStudentId());

        // prepareStatement.setInt(2,studentId.getInt(1));
        prepareStatement.setInt(2, autoId);
        prepareStatement.setString(3, studentContactDetails.getName());
        prepareStatement.setString(4, studentContactDetails.getAddress());
        prepareStatement.setString(5, studentContactDetails.getPhoneNo());
        prepareStatement.setString(6, "sysadmin");
        prepareStatement.setString(7, DateUtil.getDate().format(date));
        prepareStatement.setString(8, "sysadmin");
        prepareStatement.setString(9, DateUtil.getDate().format(date));
        prepareStatement.executeUpdate();
        while (studentId.next()) {
            autoId = studentId.getInt(1);
            System.out.println(autoId);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`studentregistration`.`student_contact_details_t`, CONSTRAINT `student_contact_details_t_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `student_details_t` (`student_id`))
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
```

Comment: I'm confused. Your title says that you are getting an error loading the database config, but the exception says you are getting a constraint violation, which means that you are connected to your database OK. Which is it?

Comment: i 'm connecting with my data base .while trying use result set generated key to get parent table primary key and insert data to child table.i am getting this exception.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that you are inserting `student_id` in table `student_contact_details_t` that does not exist in `student_details_t` table voilating the foreign key constraint that you set up during `student_contact_details_t` table creation.

So you have to first insert in table `student_details_t` then insert in `student_contact_details_t` with `student_id`

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate that the student id exist in the student table student_details_t.

If the student doesn't exist in student_details_t then you can't insert in the related table student_contact_details_t.

In this scenario you should tell the user that "student XXX doesn't exist".